# bad operand types for binary operator '+' during printing enum

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

I'm working with JavaFX application and trying to create separate enum with all paths. Here is the code.

```
enum Paths {
    STYLE_SHEETS("../stylesheets"),
    CONTROLLER("../controller"),
    CONNECTION("../connection"),
    RESOURCE("../resource"),
    VIEWS("../views"),
    APPLICATION("../application"),
    MOVE_UP("..");

    private final String path;

    private Paths(final String value) {
        this.path = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return path;
    }
}
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP + Paths.VIEWS);
    }
}
```

But when I try to combine two enum's instance I got the error.

```
Test.java:29: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
                System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP + Paths.VIEWS);
                                                 ^
  first type:  Paths
  second type: Paths
1 error
```

1) Why I'm getting this error?

2) Is it a good way to create enum of paths and use in controller class where you want to access the directory. **( This is optional question. Answering this question will be bonus for me. )**

Comment: `System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP.name() + Paths.VIEWS.name());` you cant concatentate two enums

Comment: @mayha Paths.MOVE_UP will return a string.

Comment: @UnKnown with the toString Methode you can turn one of the enums into a string then it works (did it for both in my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can solve this pretty quick bye adding the `toString()` Methode.

Why do you Need the `toString()` Methode?

> Because it would be ambiguous. Java only converts + to String#append, when it knows at least one part should be a string. – @Silverclaw

Updated Code:

```
enum Paths {
STYLE_SHEETS("../stylesheets"),
CONTROLLER("../controller"),
CONNECTION("../connection"),
RESOURCE("../resource"),
VIEWS("../views"),
APPLICATION("../application"),
MOVE_UP("..");

private final String path;

private Paths(final String value) {
    this.path = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return path;
}
}
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP.toString() + Paths.VIEWS.toString());
}
}
```

Edited to Complete:

For more understanding, Java needs to solve `+` operator first then it will pass to `System.out.println();` So as you expecting `toString()` should be invoke, it will not call because no one enum is going to `println();` they need to solve + operator first, and Enum have nothing with `+` that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Why? can you explain? `System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP);` it will work fine and I will get String.

Comment: @UnKnown you cant use the + Operator between 2 enums (see Mureiniks answer)

Comment: Because it would be ambiguous. Java only converts + to String#append, when it knows at least one part should be a string.

Comment: @UnKnown `System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP);` works because it calls by default `Object::toString`

Comment: @JordiCastilla That's is the reason understood. toString() will work later when both enum goes to System.out.println(); so in my problem java needs to solve + operator first. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `+` operator between two enum values, as the error says. At least of the operands should be a string in order for Java to implicitly convert the other one to a string too. E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP.toString() + Paths.VIEWS);
    // Here -------------------------^
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I need this? I already override `toString();` method in enum so it should work.

Comment: @UnKnown overriding `toString()` has nothing to do with it. You still need to signal to java you want to the `+` operator to act as a concatination operator between two strings somehow.

Comment: Why? It looks bugs in java. can you explain it more please? why Java required this signal? can you give me link to read about this one.

Comment: It is no bug. The `+` operation is performed before `println` is called, so at the point of `+` Java doesn't know anything about `String` being wanted, so it only sees two enums being added.

Comment: @UnKnown I link to the relevant part of JLS in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38656982/3788176).

Answer (score 1):

Either you explicitly call the toString() method

```
System.out.println(Paths.MOVE_UP.toString() + Paths.VIEWS.toString());
```

or you add an empty string in front of your enums (as you'd do to concatenate integers instead of adding them up)

```
System.out.println("" + Paths.MOVE_UP + Paths.VIEWS);
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is specified in [JLS Sec 15.18 "Additive Operators"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Neither of your operands is a `String`; neither of your operands is convertible to a primitive numeric type. So:

> a compile-time error occurs

You can either force (at least) one of the operands to be a `String`:

```
Paths.MOVE_UP.toString() + Paths.VIEWS
```

or pre-concatenate with the empty string:

```
"" + Paths.MOVE_UP + Paths.VIEWS
```

which is equivalent to

```
("" + Paths.MOVE_UP) + Paths.VIEWS
```